# How to disable JsonProperty or JsonIgnore on test

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, jackson-modules

If there a way to disable `@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)` or `@JsonIgnore` on testing?

I am trying to test my `createUser()` but I need `user.getPassword()` method be enabled when I parse my `User` object.

If I comment the `@JsonProperty` line it works but if that I do so, the password field will be returned on `GET /users or GET /users/{id}` method.

Here is my test

```
@Test
public void createUser() throws Exception {
    User user = UserFactory.newUser();
    String userJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user);

    LOGGER.info("User to register: " + userJson);

    mockMvc.perform(post("/users")
            .content(userJson)
            .contentType(contentType))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(notNullValue())));
}
```

The method that create a new user:

```
public static User newUser() {
    Fairy fairy = Fairy.create();
    Person person = fairy.person();

    User user = new User();
    user.setName(person.getFirstName());
    user.setLastName(person.getLastName());
    user.setEmail(person.getEmail());
    user.setUsername(person.getUsername());
    user.setPassword(person.getPassword());
    user.setSex(person.isMale() ? User.Sex.MALE : User.Sex.FEMALE);
    user.setPhone(person.getTelephoneNumber());
    user.setCountry(person.getAddress().getCity());

    return user;
}
```

This is the json it got after serialize `User` object with the `ObjectMapper`:

```
{
    "createdAt" : null,
    "updatedAt" : null,
    "name" : "Jasmine",
    "lastName" : "Neal",
    "email" : "jasmineneal@yahoo.com",
    "username" : "jasminen",
    "sex" : "FEMALE",
    "phone" : "321-104-989",
    "country" : "San Francisco"
}
```

**UserController.class method**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity store(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
    userService.store(user);
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(user, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

**User.class property**

```
@Column(name = "password", length = 100)
@NotNull(message = "error.password.notnull")
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY) // If I comment this, it works
private String password;
```

Is it a workaround for this?

Comment: I'd advise against reusing the `User` model in your test for the sole purpose of having JSON serialization for free. This way, your `User` model is tightly coupled to your test. If you happen to have a bug in your JSON mapping, you will have a hard time detecting it

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I appreciate it. What do you recommend me to do? Maybe a class that handle this request and then parse it to an `User` instance?

Comment: As a minimum, I'd create a separate `UserModel` for your test to make sure changes to the original `User` won't affect the way the input data for your test is handled. In this model, you could simply drop the `WRITE_ONLY` flag. Alternatively, you could simply perform your request passing a simple map as the body

Answer (score 3):

You can disable all Jackson annotations by adding the following line:

```
objectMapper.disable(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS);
```

For more info, you can check this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations).

In your case, this should work:

```
@Test
public void createUser() throws Exception {
User user = UserFactory.newUser();
objectMapper.disable(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS);
String userJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user);

LOGGER.info("User to register: " + userJson);

mockMvc.perform(post("/users")
        .content(userJson)
        .contentType(contentType))
        .andExpect(status().isCreated())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(notNullValue())));
}
```