# Using Jackson annotations with JsonPatch

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson, json-patch

If I have the following dto in spring boot

```
public class PersonDto {

@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
private Long id;

@NotBlank
private String name;
    
//@NotNull
@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
private Integer age;
}
```

And I want to perform a HTTP PATCH following [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) standard, which is implemented by the [JsonPatch](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-patch) library, I would write something like this to get the patched JsonNode

```
JsonNode patched = patch.apply(objectMapper.convertValue(target, JsonNode.class));
```

However when performing a patch operation like the following, the `@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)` won't make any effect(meaning that age would be set to 12)

```
[ {"op":"replace","path":"/age","value": 12} ]
```

I've also tried the following afterwards

```
return objectMapper.treeToValue(patched, PersonDto.class)
```

But here the age is set to null

So, the expected behaviour I want to achieve is the following:

Whenever I receive a patch operation that attempts to replace the value of 'age', I want that operation to be ignored, since age is read-only.

I know I could create if statements in the controller to check each patch operation and ignore it if it attempts to change a field that I want to be read-only like age, but I would rather do this with jackson annotations. Is this possible?

I did follow [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-json-patch) tutorial in case you want to check it out

Comment: You can disable the `USE_ANNOTATIONS` feature of `ObjectMapper` in the layer where you are processing patch requests. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57322279/2039546

Comment: Im sorry, but could you elaborate more on that, I just dont see how that solves my problem, since I want to use the notations not disable them